# Determine the resultant displacement of the airplane analytically

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors

An airplane travels 200 miles due west and then 150 miles 60° north of west. The direction i get is 21.64° north of west but the book's answer is 25.17° north of east....I don't understand how so?

Comment: Homework questions are generally closed as off-topic here. This question doesn't show any attempt at finding the answer either.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what u said?

Comment: If you want a precise answer, you need to consider that the plane is flying across the surface of a sphere.

Comment: I tried my magnitude matched the books answer but the direction didn't. In the book the direction is given 25.17° north of east...i dont understand how.....Should i add this part on the body of my ques?

Comment: If both motions are to the west, there is no way that the answer can be to the east.  The book has made an error.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a flat surface, I get the resultant angle as arctan(129.9/275) north of west.